# Accuracy assessment 0.99 Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, accuracy-assessment

I've successfully run my classification using Landsat but my accuracy gives me 0.99 which might be too good to be true. Here is my script. What might the problem be?

```
//Define AOI and predefined training sites. Just Copy asset ID.
var AOI = ee.FeatureCollection('users/KanyaXongo/AOI');
Map.addLayer(AOI);

//Load Imagery

//SENTINEL IMAGERY
//var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED');

//LANDSAT 5,7,8 IMAGERY
//var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR")
var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
//var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
//Filter Images
   .filterDate('2000-06-01', '2000-06-30')//Date
   .filterBounds(AOI)//Area
   .sort('CLOUD_COVER')//To select the image with less or no cloud cover
   .first()
   .clip(AOI);
   
//Visualise true colour composite.
var visParamsTrue = {bands:['B3','B2','B1'], min:0,max:3000, gamma:1.4};//Min and max values for the surface reflectance data
Map.addLayer(image,visParamsTrue,'LANDSAT 1998');
Map.centerObject(AOI,8);//To zoom into the area of interest

//Training Data
//Training points must be FeatureCollection
//Class numbers should start from 1
var label = 'Class';
var bands = ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7'];
var input = image.select(bands);

//Merge training data
var training = Forestry.merge(Water).merge(Bare_Land);

//Overlay the points on the image to start training
var train_image = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties: ['Class'],
  scale: 30
});
//print(train_image);

//train classifier
//var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(train_image, label, bands);
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  features: train_image,
  classProperty: 'Class',
  inputProperties: bands,
});
//run classification
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);
print(classified.getInfo());
//Colour palette
//Map.centerObject(training, 15);
var landcoverPalette = [
  '#387242', // forest
  '#aec3d4', // water
  //'6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',  // shrub, grass
  //'111149', // wetlands
  //'cdb33b', // croplands
  //'cc0013', // urban
 // '33280d', // crop mosaic
  //'d7cdcc', // snow and ice
  '#f7e084', // barren
];
Map.addLayer(classified, {palette: landcoverPalette, min: 1, max: 3}, 'Classification');

//ACCURACY ASSESSMENT

// SPLIT THE TRAINING DATA INTO TRAINING (70-80%) AND VALIDATION DATA (20-30%)
var trainingData = train_image.randomColumn();
var trainSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.8));
var testSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random', 0.2));

//CLASSIFY testSet TO GET THE CONFUSION MATRIX
var confusionMatrix = ee.ConfusionMatrix(testSet.classify(classifier)
.errorMatrix({
  actual:'Class',
  predicted:'classification'
}));
print('Confusion Matrix:',confusionMatrix);
print("Overall Accuracy:",confusionMatrix.accuracy());
```

Link to script is: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2FKanyaXongo%2FLearning%3AClassification%20Script

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared your asset, so I cannot run the script. But just looking at it, I see that all data used for validation has also been used for training.

You correctly split `train_image` into `trainSet` and `testSet`, but you use `train_image`, not `traingSet` for training the classifier. This would explain your high accuracy.